# Is there a way to invite a user to Asana through their API

Tags: asana

I was wondering if there's an exposed API to invite a user to a workspace/project/task, thereby adding the user to the workspace.

Comment: We'd love to see the User API to expand to be as comprehensive as the others - support for create / invite, modify user details, and disabling or deleting users. My organization prefers to manage as many tools as possible with our scripts and APIs make our lives much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time, I've read the documentation cover-to-cover as of 4/23/2012 and that functionality is not yet there (from what I can tell).